# jquery: assigning event from string

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using ASP.net and it creates a pager for a gridview that has the following HTML:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(.....)" class="MyLink">pagenumber</a></td>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on the cell but not the actual content of the cell, the script doesn't trigger because it's not linked to the whole cell.

So I'm writing a small script to extract the link and assign its value to a click event handler for each cell. This is what I have so far:

```
    $('.MyLink').each(function () {

        var TheLink = $(this).attr('href');
        var CellContent = $(this).html();
       // alert(CellContent);

        var LinkExtract = TheLink.split(":");
        //alert(LinkExtract[1]);

        var PagerCell = $(this).parent();

        $(PagerCell).click(function () { LinkExtract[1]; }); //problem here
        $(PagerCell).html('');
        $(PagerCell).html(CellContent);

    });
```

Both alerts return the expected content. However, the click event doesn't work.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would utilize eval() to do what you are attempting. Warning, eval() can be strongly abused by malicious users so you need to use it judiciously.

```
$('.MyLink').each(function () {

    var TheLink = $(this).attr('href');
    var CellContent = $(this).html();
   // alert(CellContent);

    var LinkExtract = TheLink.split(":");
    //alert(LinkExtract[1]);

    var PagerCell = $(this).parent();

    $(PagerCell).click(function () { eval(LinkExtract[1]); }); //problem here
    $(PagerCell).html('');
    $(PagerCell).html(CellContent);

});
```

Comment: ok, perfect! What's the risk with using eval in this context?

Comment: @frenchie it evaluates the string found and calls functions... so as a user, I could save the html of your page and my desktop. Then alter the onclick to call javascript of my own ... that is a huge security risk. Make sure you add some check statements to this code that verifies what is in the string before using eval()

Comment: Why so much overkill? If you want to click the link when the parent is clicked, just tell jQuery to do so!

Comment: Actually there's a problem with this approach too: normally the link triggers a partial ajax postback without a full page reload. However I noticed that even thought the event is registered, there's now a full page postback. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @frenchie try this in the click function: `function () { eval(LinkExtract[1]);e.preventDefault();  }`

Comment: @jamietre: nope, still doing a full page reload.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just trigger the `.click()` handler of the link when the main cell is clicked, which clicks the link artificially:

```
$('.MyLink').parent().click(function() {
    $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

Comment: @Frenchie Try Blender's approach. This is what came to mind when writing out my answer.